# How android annotation Generated Code Affect previous non Generated code?

Tags: android, android-annotations

I am curious about how Android annotation works so i start reading it's [google wiki](https://code.google.com/archive/p/androidannotations/wikis/HowItWorks.wiki) but i thinks it's still a mystery , because it says:

> A subclass is generated for each @EActivity(R.layout.something) where
>   onCreate method will will be created with super.onCreate() and set
>   content View as R.layout.something

But Real Question is what if i have already implemented some stuff in onCreate method of Activity where I put `@EActivity(R.layout.something)`.

Other beginner Question is what are the best possible tips to avoid `App not responding` dialog `(i know about not doing long processing stuff in Uithread)` what about other possible situations where i can get this Message while using AA ?

Thanks is advance

Comment: This are actually two unrelated questions and both are somewhat unclear / too broad.

Answer (score 1):

You can put any code in your `Activity`s `onCreate()` method, because the generated class will call every overriden method with `super.XXX()`. Code in your class will be never ignored.

However remember that injected resources are only available in `@AfterInject` annotated methods, and injected views are only available in `@AfterViews` annotated methods.

The other question is pretty general indeed: you should not run any long-running operations on the main thread, you have to move them to another thread. There are lot of solutions for that in the Android API and other libraries.

Comment: i didn't quite understood the concept of AfterInject and AfterViews what's the difference

Comment: The first is called after beans and resources are injected. The second is called after views are injected.